# Why do some crowdloan accounts have free balance?

Tags: parachain, account, crowdloan

For example, paraID 2000. The slot pallet is holding in reserve only the amount of balance that is reserved, however the total crowlodan account (which should hold the amount of tokens raised on the crowdloan) holds also some free balance.

```
  {
    paraID: 2000,
    account: '13UVJyLnbVp77Z2t6qZV4fNpRjDHppL6c87bHcZKG48tKJad',
    'slots.leases': 29945909,
    'balance.reserved': 29945909,
    'balance.free': 2570072,
    'balance.free (as %)': 7.9
  }
```

I've noticed too that the free balance of this crowdloan account is never the same percentage of the total balance, and that not all crowdloan accounts have free balance (for example, moonbeam has everything reserved).

Note that this is related to the crowdloan account, and not the sovereign account of the parachain on the relay chain. Context on these [here](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/109/how-do-parachain-crowdloan-accounts-work).

Answer (score 2):

Polkadot has a [candle auction mechanism](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-auction) to assign parachain slots to different parachain projects. This mechanism always lasts a fixed amount of blocks, and when it ends, the VRF runs and randomly selects the block at which exactly the candle went off. At that block height, is where the winner is decided.

With this in mind, all the contributions *before* the "candle went off" to the crowdloan will be reserved, however all the tokens that were contributed *after* the "candle went off" will be free balance on the crowdloan account.